# Menu in FragmentActivity is not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, mapfragment

I have an issue with adding Menu in my FragmentActivity.

I have added a MapFragment and some buttons in my FragmentActivity:

[image]

Then I'm trying to add optionsMenu above the map but my code does not works (there is no errors during running the app).

Here is my code of FragmentActivity:

```
<pre>package com.bugsnguns.kartta;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.maps_menu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using Toolbar in the Activity?

Comment: @SahilLombar Thanks! Problem solved by changing FragmentActivity to AppCompatActivity without using Toolbar. onCreateOptionsMenu method is enough with AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `ToolBar` where you can inflate your `Optionsmenu`. You can see how to add a toolbar (App Bar) in the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Your code to inflate the menu should work just fine after adding a `Toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

Add a ToolBar to the Activity layout

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   />
```

And add in the activity

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But setSupportActionBar does not work with FragmentActivity in my code. I'm trying to change FragmentActivity to AppCompatActivity to use our code (it seems legal because AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity) but the app crashes in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To get the toolbar or action bar in FragmentActivity, you'll have to assign a theme to your activity which is compatible with FragmentActivity. I struggled with this myself but everything worked as soon as I assigned a Holo theme to my activity in the Manifest.